# Should we burninate or retag [edge]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge) tag (<s>716</s> 391 questions)

> "Edge detection in image progress etc. -- For the Microsoft Edge
>   browser, use the [microsoft-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) tag."

is very similar to the [edge-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge-detection) tag (537 questions)

> Edge detection is a tool in computer vision used to find
>   discontinuities (edges) in images

However despite the tag wiki it appears that the majority of the 716 question have nothing to do with edge detection.

Many are obviously related to [microsoft-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) (1,150 questions).

And some have nothing to do with either, but simply relate to "edges" in general, e.g.:

- [DFS after remove some edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584614/dfs-after-remove-some-edge) (graph theory edges)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775123/adobe-edge-javascript-animate-cloned-element (Adobe Edge, a web development tool)
- [EDGE: Opacity on SVG lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677682/edge-opacity-on-svg-lines) (drawing edges in SVG)
- [How to determine the iOS connection type (Edge, 3G, 4G, Wifi)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379900/how-to-determine-the-ios-connection-type-edge-3g-4g-wifi) (The Edge cellular network protocol)

I think the tag is simply too ambiguous to be useful. And I am not sure the default meaning of "edge" per the tag wiki is very intuitive, so I don't know if we should make edge a synonym of edge-detection instead of one of the other possible meanings.

Perhaps burninate it outright, then blacklist it from orbit?

Comment: Agreed. We shouldn't be living on the [edge]. I hereby pl[edge] to help burninate this. Maybe we could use a h[edge] fund?

Comment: The mandatory burninate pun: "should we edge away"?

Comment: This tag is driving me over the [edge]

Comment: One step closer to the [edge] - which has the potential benefit of having a soundtrack. On the other hand, it's Linkin Park: so...

Comment: Throw it over the [edge]

Comment: If there's a question with a higher pun/content ratio I'd love to see it...

Comment: `Many are related to [tag:microsoft-edge]` I should hope not... I worked hard (with others) to retag those as I found them for nearly a year. An editor's work is never done... *sigh*.

Comment: [edge] now has 503 questions, very much divided between [microsoft-edge] and [edge-detection]. Some are related to graph edges (for which there exists [edges]). This tag needs to go away, it is ambiguous.

Comment: This may be an [edge] case.

Answer (score 9):

I just retagged the Adobe Edge questions that had the [edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge) tag ([search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bedge%5D+Adobe): `[edge] Adobe`) with [adobe-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-edge) instead. A couple on that search were MS Edge related so some care was needed.

This should be done for [edge-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge-detection) and [microsoft-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) questions as well.

#### Update

Microsoft Edge questions tagged [edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge) should all be cleaned up now. Thanks for your [help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343021/should-we-burninate-or-retag-edge#comment443654_343101) Tyler!

Comment: I just adjusted 50 questions from [tag:edge] to [tag:microsoft-edge]. I'll go through some more later.

Comment: You probably also want to retag [these \[internet-explorer\]\[edge\] questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer+edge)